# How to load simple bitmap file win32

Tags: winapi, bitmap

i want to test some simple Win32 that uses bitmap. Here is code i got from Googling.

```
#include <windows.h>

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void DisplayError(DWORD, const char*);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char szClassName[ ] = "WindowsApp";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                LPSTR lpszArgument,
                int nFunsterStil)

{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default color as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
       0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
       szClassName,         /* Classname */
       "Windows App",       /* Title Text */
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | SS_BITMAP,
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
       544,                 /* The programs width */
       375,                 /* and height in pixels */
       HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
       NULL,                /* No menu */
       hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
       NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
       );

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nFunsterStil);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}

/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HBITMAP g_hbitmap = NULL;
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_CREATE: {
            g_hbitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                       "D:\\zhbackground.bmp",
                                       IMAGE_BITMAP,
                                       LR_DEFAULTSIZE,
                                       LR_DEFAULTSIZE,
                                       LR_LOADFROMFILE);
            if(!g_hbitmap) {
                DisplayError(GetLastError(), "Error loading bitmap");
            }
            break;
        }
        case WM_PAINT: {
            HDC dc;
            HDC memdc;
            HGDIOBJ old;
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            BITMAP bm;
            dc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            DisplayError(GetLastError(), "BeginPaint");
            memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
            DisplayError(GetLastError(), "CreateCompatibleDC");
            old = SelectObject(memdc, g_hbitmap);
            DisplayError(GetLastError(), "SelectObject");
            GetObject(g_hbitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
            DisplayError(GetLastError(), "GetObject");
            BitBlt(dc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            DisplayError(GetLastError(), "BitBlt");
            SelectObject(memdc, old);
            DisplayError(GetLastError(), "SelectObject");
            DeleteDC(memdc);
            DisplayError(GetLastError(), "DeleteDC");
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
            DisplayError(GetLastError(), "EndPaint");
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY:
            DeleteObject(g_hbitmap);
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void DisplayError(DWORD dw, const char* szFuncName)
{
     LPSTR buff;
     FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER,
              NULL,
              dw,
              LANG_NEUTRAL,
              (LPSTR)&buff,
              0,
              NULL);
     MessageBox(NULL, buff, szFuncName, MB_OK);
}
```

The problem is the window just display nothing, so i make a call to GetLastError() and try to see what's going on. From there, i got that the file was loaded (i guess as g_hbitmap != NULL) and the other DisplayError() shows the operation completed successfully.

Any ideas? Thanks for advance!

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger and you'll see that the value of `g_hbitmap` in the `WM_PAINT` handler is not the same as the value created by the `WM_CREATE` handler.

Comment: @alk: Thanks for quick reply alk. I try your advise and the window still shows nothing. In my opinion, we have to specify what bitmap to show to the window, don't we? So, we have to catch the WM_PAINT message. CMIIW.

Comment: I was providing a debugging hint, not a solution. Now that you see that the variable is not retaining its value, you need to fix that.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks for quick reply Chen. I try your advise by move the LoadImage() to WM_PAINT handler, then as you expected, it was INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. What makes me wonder is the image now shown in the window, but its size is so little. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @all: I've finally got it works! I just change LR_DEFAULTSIZE to 0. Thanks for all your reply guys!

Comment: Your problem is that `g_hbitmap` (despite its name) is a local variable, which means that each time the function is called, it gets a new copy. You set the value in the `WM_CREATE` handler but use it in the `WM_PAINT` handler, which is a different function call. You need to make `g_hbitmap` a global variable.